# Error while opening Page Layouts and site templates

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, page-layout

I have create a sitecolumn and content type using Visual Studio. Then I have created a pagelayout using the contenttype in 'Design Manager' and deployed that two files (html, aspx) using Visual Studio. Now, I'm not able to open the 'Page Layouts and site templates'. I'm getting the below error! Expecting a help...

```
Application error when access /_layouts/15/AreaTemplateSettings.aspx, Error=There are no page layout files available in the master page library of the top-level site. Add one or more page layouts to this library before you create a page or set page properties.   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.WebControls.DropDownListWithDetails.ItemInfo.PopulateDataList(PageLayout[] layouts, SPSite site)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.CodeBehind.AreaTemplateSettingsPage.InitializeDefaultPageLayoutSection()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.CodeBehind.AreaTemplateSettingsPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

EDIT

I have created a new layout through UI and changed the page layout for testing in a page. But, after that I forgot to add the current page layouts back to the site collection. Is that may be a cause for this error? How can we add these layouts back to site collection ? (Setting it as current layouts) Any powershell scripts ?

Comment: How are you deploying the Page Layout? If you are using VS for deployment, no need to deploy HTML file..

Comment: I have created a new layout through UI and changed the page layout for testing in a page. But, after that I forgot to add the current page layouts back to the site collection. Is that may be a cause for this error? How can we add these layouts back to site collection ? (Setting it as current layouts)